# Como alinhar ao centro um elemento maior que a div com CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Preciso fazer um botão redondo que seja maior que a div como este da foto
[image: Botao de menu]

Porém no meu código não estou conseguindo alinhar com as funcoes que costumo usar e meu resultado está sendo esse: [image: Botao de menu]

Qual propriedade css, ou uma forma de implementação posso usar pra resolver esse problema?

```css
.barramenu{
    position: static;
    height: 100%;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(162, 109, 109);
    text-align: center;
}
.barramenu .bordabotao{
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #21dc40;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    /* justify center esta centralizando o icone */
    justify-content: center;
    /* tentativas de alinhar circulo */
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
```

```html
<div class="barramenu">
        <!-- espaco para a logo -->
            <p>Logo</p>
            <!-- div que faz o circulo e dentro dela abriga um botao -->
            <div class="bordabotao"> 
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="menu">
                    <span class="icon">.<ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                </a>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos lá, primeiramente, vamos remover a `margin:auto` do circulo e definir a div pai `.barramenu` para ter `display:flex` e alinhar o conteúdo ao centro dela para alinhar o círculo.

Depois, mais um detalhe, você tenta alinhar o ícone ao centro com `justify-content` e `align-items`, mas não tem a propriedade `display:flex`, então as propriedades anteriores não funcionam.

Aqui seria o código funcionando:

```css
.barramenu{
    position: static;
    height: 100%;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(162, 109, 109);
    text-align: center;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
}
.barramenu .bordabotao{
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #21dc40;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* justify center esta centralizando o icone */
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* tentativas de alinhar circulo */
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="barramenu">
  <!-- espaco para a logo -->
  <p>Logo</p>
  <!-- div que faz o circulo e dentro dela abriga um botao -->
  <div class="bordabotao"> 
    <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="menu">
      <span class="icon">.<ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```